# Background image change when clicking a image

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to change the background a following page depending on what icon is clicked and I'm not sure whats wrong with my code! This is just a test page (Please excuse the weird code, but i need it in the actual site itself!)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

 body   {

background: url('<?php echo $_GET['image']; ?>';

}


</style>


<script>
    function showWeather(Weather) {
     //alert(Weather);
        myform.weather.value=Weather;
    //  alert(Weather);

    // ._Weather
        myform.submit();


}
</script>


<link href="teststyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body background="images/gradientsky.jpg"> 
<div id="weather">

<ul id="nav-reflection">
<form method="post" action="cloudy_name.php" id="myform">
    <li class="button-color-1"><a href="cloudy_name.php?image=images/cloudysky.png" onclick="showWeather('cloudy');" title="My fancy link"><img src="images/cloudybubble.png" width="211" height="180" align="left"></a></li> 

    <input type="hidden" name="weather" value="whatever">
</form>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are going to change the bg of the destination page?

Comment: yeah, the destination's page's background is changed, that page being cloudy_name.php

Comment: Since you use `window.location` for your redirection, you can't change style in the destination page. Also, you should put quotes around "test" when you are calling `getElementById`.

Comment: Didn't know that Guillaume, is there some other way I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple problems here, I'll try and address them:

```
<form method="post" action="cloudy_name.php" id="myform">
        <li class="button-color-1"><a href="javascript:showWeather('cloudysky')" onclick="changeBgImage(images/cloudysky)" title="My fancy link"><img src="images/cloudybubble.png" width="211" height="180" align="left"></a></li>
</form>
```

1. You're missing the "ul" wrapper. List-items can not exist by themselves.
2. You're saying showWeather('cloudy'). 'cloudysky' is not a full filename, so maybe it's cloudysky.jpg?
3. The user is clicking a link and being sent to another page, so any changes you make here with javascript won't stick once the user returns.
4. document.getElementById(test) needs to reference a string, like so document.getElementById("test")

Give those a shot and report back.

Comment: Thanks for finding my stupid mistakes x_x! But it unfortunately didn't fix my problem! :[

Comment: Updated the code above. I believe I fixed the issues you found.

Answer (score 0):

Your changeBgImage function didn't pass through the string 'image'

Try this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeBgImage (image) { // added Image
            var element = document.getElementById('test');
            element.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+image+"')"; // added single qoutes around image
            // Took out window.location - see comments below for explanation
            return false;// Added to stop Link execution
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">
    <form method="post" action="cloudy_name.php" id="myform">
        <li class="button-color-1"><a href="#" onclick="showWeather('cloudy'); changeBgImage('images/cloudysky.png');" title="My fancy link"><img src="images/cloudybubble.png" width="211" height="180" align="left"></a></li>
    </form>
</div>
```

I added all javascript functions into the onclick, both `showWeather` and `changeBgImage`

See comments below.

Comment: I took out the window.location as it would change the page. If you are needing it to save it, you may have to use a cookie in order to keep saved background image on the system, or if using a Server side language and they are logged in, you can save it through the database.

Comment: Added `return false;` to make the link not execute, however if you need it to, you can take that out.

Comment: hmm its still not linking to the page though, and I need to have the "javascript:showWeather('cloudy')" in there because that ends up getting used as a value thats put into a database.

Comment: hmm still isn't working...am I support to put the image into the  function changeBgImage (image) ?

Comment: http://www.tcnjart.com/christineaustin/whethertheweather/test.html there is the link if you would like to see it yourself

Comment: Oh, your trying to change body's background image? change  `getElementById('test')` to `body`

Comment: in the test.html you are having it forward to another page, are you wanting that?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
function changeBgImage (image) {
    var element = document.body('test');
    element.style.backgroundImage = "url("+image+")";` like this? cause its not working either :/

Comment: Well, in the site there will be 6 images similar to `cloudybubble.png` when you click one, it will lead you to a page (called `cloudy_name.php` but will eventually be changed to `name.php`) where the background image (located in the body) will change. (Ex.- you press the cloudy bubble to get a cloudy background,  the sunner bubbles gives you a sunny background)

Comment: I am thinking you are wanting a different outcome. You want it to go to another page? Which if that is the case, on the next page you can save the variable in a hidden value or a javascript cookie. and if you are using PHP it is even easier. Just depends on how you are wanting to do the project, but it sounds like now, it is more than just a background change on the fly, but you are trying to save the value of the weather img and then on the next page have the background image change. make sense?

Comment: in that case chepe263 has the correct answer. You are wanting to change the next page to have this in the head: `<style>background: url('<php echo $_GET['image']; ?>';</style>` and have this change on the current page, and you don't need the javascript `<a href="cloudy_name.php?image=images/cloudysky.png" onclick="showWeather('cloudy');" title="My fancy link"><img src="images/cloudybubble.png" width="211" height="180" align="left"></a>`

Comment: Hmm, its not working, knowing me I'm probably doing something wrong. I put the fixed code in my main post, do you see any errors in it?

Comment: does anything go inside `('test')` and i also figure another easy way to do it is to define each body of each page with an id and give them there individual backgrounds that way.

Answer (score -2):

IDEA: on the  link create a link to a php file. something like chg_bg.php?image=cloudy

On the php file, create some code to set the background

```
<style>
    background: url('<php echo $_GET['image']; ?>';
</style>
```

Comment: So apparently I should be using your method! I updated my code above in an attempt to fix it but its still not working, maybe I have a stupid error I can't see?

Comment: Create some cookie or session variable to store the value. I read it from @Joshua Pack's comment